# How does xs Pattern in Haskell work?

Tags: haskell

How does this code work? I have not defined a x.

```
describeList :: [a] -> String
describeList xs = "The list is " ++ case xs of
                                              [ ] -> "empty."
                                              [x] -> "a singleton list."
                                              xs -> "a longer list."
```

Comment: Have you looked up how pattern matching works? That will answer this pretty readily.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Why not provide a link to somewhere the questioneer can look it up? (Here is one such link: http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#case-expressions)

Comment: Turn on warnings. You'll discover the the `xs` in the `case` is shadowing the outer definition of `xs`. Indeed, variables that appear in patterns, e.g. `x` above, are being _defined_ by the `case`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With *explicit parenthesization*, your code is

```
describeList :: [a] -> String
describeList xs = "The list is " ++ (case xs of 
                                        { [ ] -> "empty."
                                        ; [x] -> "a singleton list."
                                        ; xs -> "a longer list."  } )
```

So the answer to your question is, this is how the pattern matching, done by `case`, works:

- In *case* `xs` matches an empty list, `[ ]`, successfully, the first alternative is used.
- In case `xs` matches a singleton list, `[x]`, the second alternative is performed, with any *pattern variables* bound to the respective parts of the *value* being matched, `xs`.
- etc.